# How to get the Initials of a Name from an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My code doesn't work. I need feedback and an efficient way to return the Initials of the First and Last name that matches the id passed to the function.

```
var contactList = [
    {
    "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
    "name": 'Niels Bohr',
    "num_messages": 62,
    },
    {
    'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
    "name": 'Max Planck',
    "num_messages": 15,
    },
    {
    "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
    "name": 'Jane Goodall',
    "num_messages": 20,
    },
    {
    "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
    "name": "Caroline Herschel",
    "num_messages": 3,
    },
]

function getInitials(id){
    // find the user object
    for (let u of contactList) {
        if (u["id"] == id){
            var initials = ''
            names = u.name.split(' ')
            for(var i; i < names.length; i++){
                initials += names[i][0]
            }
            // return the initials
            return initials
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell ur expected output

Comment: Expected output should be "NB" for the first id and so on...

Answer (score 2):

First of all find the the item whose `id` matches given `id` using **[find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**. Then `split()` its `name` and map it to its `name[0]` and then `join()`

```js
var contactList = [
    {
    "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
    "name": 'Niels Bohr',
    "num_messages": 62,
    },
    {
    'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
    "name": 'Max Planck',
    "num_messages": 15,
    },
    {
    "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
    "name": 'Jane Goodall',
    "num_messages": 20,
    },
    {
    "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
    "name": "Caroline Herschel",
    "num_messages": 3,
    },
]
function getInitials(id){
    let obj = contactList.find(item => item.id === id);
 return obj && obj.name.split(' ').map(a => a[0]).join('');
}
console.log(getInitials('7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6'))
console.log(getInitials('17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564'))
console.log(getInitials('b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44'))
console.log(getInitials('0'))
```

Comment: map and join,  functional power when exists charAt .

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón what you mean?

Comment: your are using a[0] to get CharAt(0) and exists charAt for this propouse.

Comment: Your code will fail if find returns undefined or if the names contain more than 1 space between the words

Comment: You should use a regex to do the split, to swallow all spaces when there are more than one: split(/\s+/)

Answer (score 1):

You could find the object, get the name and build the initals.

```js
function getInitials(array, id) {
    var temp = array.find(o => o.id === id);
    return temp && temp.name.split(' ').map(([c]) => c).join('');
}

var contactList = [{ id: 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07', name: 'Niels Bohr', num_messages: 62 }, { id: '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6', name: 'Max Planck', num_messages: 15 }, { id: 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44', name: 'Jane Goodall', num_messages: 20 }, { id: '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564', name: "Caroline Herschel", num_messages: 3 }];

console.log(getInitials(contactList, 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44'));
console.log(getInitials(contactList, '000'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a succint way to do it with `filter`, `map`, `shift` and a regex in a single chain of operations. The technique will work with any number of spaces, see the example below and will return `undefined` if the contact id is not found.

First, you filter the array for the correct id, this returns an array (could be empty) on which you map to extract the initials with `String.match`, the regex and  `Array.join`. You then shift the first element out to get the result, `shift` won't raise an error if there is no element and will simply return `undefined`.

Here are two possible regex for extracting the initials:

- `/\b(\w)/g`
- `/(?<=(\s+|^))(\w)/g`

The first regex uses `\b` to match word boundaries while `\w` will match any word character, so the regex `\b(\w)` will capture the first character of every word. This regex will fail when the names are separated with dashes, as the dash will count as a word separator.

The second regex will match every first word character using the positive lookbehind `(?<=(\s+|^))` which checks for spaces or the beginning of the string.

```js
const contactList = [{
  "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
  "name": '   Niels        Bohr',
  "num_messages": 62,
}, {
  'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
  "name": 'Max Planck    ',
  "num_messages": 15,
}, {
  "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
  "name": '  Jane Goodall',
  "num_messages": 20,
}, {
  "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
  "name": "Caroline Herschel",
  "num_messages": 3,
}];

function getInitials(id) {
  return contactList
    .filter(contact => contact.id === id)
    .map(contact => contact.name.match(/(?<=(\s+|^))(\w)/g).join(''))
    .shift();
}

console.log(getInitials('17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564'));
console.log(getInitials('b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44'));
console.log(getInitials('7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6'));
console.log(getInitials('e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07'));
console.log(getInitials('123'));
```

Comment: What does the regex do, can you explain the piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```js
var contactList = [
    {
    "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
    "name": 'Niels Bohr',
    "num_messages": 62,
    },
    {
    'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
    "name": 'Max Planck',
    "num_messages": 15,
    },
    {
    "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
    "name": 'Jane Goodall',
    "num_messages": 20,
    },
    {
    "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
    "name": "Caroline Herschel",
    "num_messages": 3,
    },
]

//here constant is your id which you passed in if condition
var str = contactList.find(x => x.id =='17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564').name.split(' ');
var result =""
for(var s of str)
   result += s.substr(0, 1)
   
console.log("Initals of \""+str+"\" is " + result);
```

Comment: Probably quicker to use find() instead of filter() since you only want one result.

Comment: Any way to use in a function where you pass the id as an argument. And without using Regex, I'm not too familiar with it. It's a take-home test and I have to explain the code

Answer (score 0):

try this, could be your needed?

```js
var contactList = [
    {
    "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
    "name": 'Niels Bohr',
    "num_messages": 62,
    },
    {
    'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
    "name": 'Max Planck',
    "num_messages": 15,
    },
    {
    "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
    "name": 'Jane Goodall',
    "num_messages": 20,
    },
    {
    "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
    "name": "Caroline Herschel",
    "num_messages": 3,
    },
]

function getInitials(id){
    // find the user object
    for (let u of contactList) {
        if (u["id"] == id){
            var initials = ''
            names = u.name.split(' ')
            console.log(names.length);
            for(var i=0; i< names.length; i++){
            
              initials+=' ' + names[i].charAt(0);
            }
            // return the initials
            console.log(initials, 'pop');
            return initials
        }
    }
}
getInitials('17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564');
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and one-liner approach using `Array.reduce` and `Array.find`
This function will return undefined if id is not present.

```js
var contactList = [
    {
    "id": 'e3d46de8c7194cb1a32275195c15dc07',
    "name": 'Niels Bohr',
    "num_messages": 62,
    },
    {
    'id': '7064c3f9c99743b2838bbd8eacafe0d6',
    "name": 'Max Planck',
    "num_messages": 15,
    },
    {
    "id": 'b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44',
    "name": 'Jane Goodall',
    "num_messages": 20,
    },
    {
    "id": '17d9d0908f454253b5337e8c1ef4b564',
    "name": "Caroline Herschel",
    "num_messages": 3,
    },
]

function getInitials(id){
  //using .find to find the element in the array
  const contact = contactList.find(contact => contact.id === id) 
  //cross checking if id is present and for that id name key is present and then using reduce function to get initials.
  return contact && contact.name && contact.name.split(' ').reduce((initial, name) => initial + name[0], '')
}

console.log(getInitials('b19e575a0d3f4151a1391452d8a47a44'))  //JG

console.log(getInitials('random'))  //undefined
```

Comment: seems nice, can you please explain the process especially the reduce part

Comment: array.reduce iterates over the array and returns the final value, you can read about it detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

```
    You have bag :
    ` for(var i; i < names.length; i++){
       initials += names[i][0]
      } `   
     1.i have to be initelased var i = 0;
```

> besides of this your  code is working